# Who to believe when seeking memory upgrades?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr2

This question is similar to the following: But asking the broad question of who to believe when seeking memory upgrades?

- [What will happen if I install more RAM than specified in manual?](https://superuser.com/q/47086/113344)
- [What happens when more RAM is installed than the motherboard supports?](https://superuser.com/q/30139/113344)

An MSI-7309 (K9N6SGM-v) Has (2) slots to fill. I am not exactly sure of the capacity.  Included below are links to conflicting specs.  I know that it can hold at least 2 Gigabytes. I would like to get 4GB in there. Without having to pay for return shipping or a restocking fee.

#### 2GB

- [MSI manual](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/K9N6SGM-V---K9N6PGM-FI---K9N6PGM-F.html#/?div=Manual)
- [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130068)
- [Memory X](http://memoryx.com/msi-k9n6sgm-v-ddr2-800mhz-ram-memory-upgrade.php)

#### 4GB

- [Tiger Direct](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=3876566&CatId=2323)
- [Kingston](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/modelsinfo.asp?SysID=35818&mfr=MSI&model=Motherboard%20K9N6SGM&search_type=&root=us&LinkBack=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kingston.com&Sys=35818-MSI-Motherboard%20K9N6SGM-V&distributor=0&submit1=Search)

#### 8GB

- [MSI](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/K9N6SGM-V---K9N6PGM-FI---K9N6PGM-F.html#/?div=Detail)
- [Crucial](http://crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=MS-7309%20%28K9N6SGM-V%29&Cat=RAM)
- [C-Net reviews](http://reviews.cnet.com/motherboards/msi-k9n6sgm-v-motherboard/1707-3049_7-32149344.html)

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard manufacturer latest manual version.

Answer (score 0):

Please see that the BIOS section specifically notes memory installs of 4GB located here: http://www.msi.com/product/mb/K9N6SGM-V---K9N6PGM-FI---K9N6PGM-F.html#/?div=BIOS

The manual was last updated in 2006, while the BIOS was last updated in 2008. I would assume then that the manual and newegg were never updated to reflect the newest memory availability.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But is it possible that the Spec page for the board is trying to be too general, and apply to all the boards in that series? I saw that firmware update changeLog you mention. That seems to indicate that the reporting of what amount of memory was recognized.  What about the memory config sites?

Comment: Even if the BIOS was updated to accept more RAM, probably the mobo hardware was not.

Comment: It's possible, yes. But I'm willing to bet that around 2006-2007 2GB memory chips were not in the norm, and a BIOS update was needed to get that memory available to that system. It looks difficult to get very specific results for this, I don't think with my google-fu we're going to be able to determine verbatim if this is possible.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the memory controller for these boards was on the CPU, not the mainboard. Hence BIOS changes allowing for more memory as it was not a CPU limitation.

Comment: @jidar. So would looking @ the stats of the processor be more helpful?

Comment: I spent a few minutes reading wikipedia on this when I first answered your question and didn't see any hard numbers backing up the memory controllers limitations. Being a 64bit processor, I'd assume this is basically a non-issue (as a memory controller).